# What is an SDB file?

Tags: pe, radare2, pe32

In the abstract, I'm just wondering what an SDB file does and what role it plays. I see [Radare2 is using them.](https://github.com/radare/radare2/tree/c0c0cba3398466661afed716f709f1fc404a752e/libr/include/sdb). Here are some of the SDB files I have under `./libr/bin/d/dll/`, what do these do?

```
./libr/bin/d/dll/csmfpapi.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/atl.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/msvbvm60.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/msi.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/mfc90u.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/msvbvm50.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/dsound.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/mfc71.sdb
./libr/bin/d/dll/olepro32.sdb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDB stands for **S**tring **D**ata**b**ase.

> `sdb` is a simple string key/value database based on [cdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cdb_(software)) disk
>   storage and supports JSON and arrays introspection.

You can see the SDB commands listed with the `k` command,

```
|Usage: k[s] [key[=value]]Sdb Query
| k foo=bar                 set value
| k foo                     show value
| k                         list keys
| ko [file.sdb] [ns]        open file into namespace
| kd [file.sdb] [ns]        dump namespace to disk
| ks [ns]                   enter the sdb query shell
| k anal/meta/*             ist kv from anal > meta namespaces
| k anal/**                 list namespaces under anal
| k anal/meta/meta.0x80404  get value for meta.0x80404 key
```

There's a whole post about it in radare2 blog, check it out [here](http://radare.today/posts/exploring-the-database/).
You can read more about it in [this link](https://github.com/radare/radare2/tree/master/shlr/sdb) from radare2's repository.
There's also a short, and not so detailed, [chapter about it](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/basic_commands/sdb.html) in r2book.

---

**Edit:** You added another question so I'll expand my answer accordingly.
These `sdb`files contain function names (DLL's exports) and their equivalent [ordinals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-functions-from-a-dll-by-ordinal-rather-than-by-name) for each `dll` in [./libr/bin/d/dll/](https://github.com/radare/radare2/tree/032aff2d556a70dfcc391d111f5aaeda2423c70a/libr/bin/d/dll). Each file contains a key-value line in this format:

```
ordinal_num=export_name
another_ordinal_num=another_export_name
```

So, if we'll take `msi.dll` from the list you've mentioned, its `sdb` file will look like this:

```
...
232=Migrate10CachedPackagesW
1=MsiAdvertiseProductA
223=MsiAdvertiseProductExA
224=MsiAdvertiseProductExW
2=MsiAdvertiseProductW
...
```

These files are then compiled by [`MakeFile`](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/libr/bin/d/Makefile). To add `sdb` files for DLL you can follow ["sdb_ordinal.md"](https://github.com/radare/radare2/blob/master/doc/sdb_ordinal.md) article from radare2 docs.

Comment: Updated the question. It'd be really great if you could expand and talk specifically about the sdb files radare ships with (now in the question).

Comment: Sure, updated with the relevant information

Comment: There's also Shim Database: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which is also .sdb file